# Why are Zucchini's refrigerated, but not acorn and spaghetti squash?

Tags: vegetables, refrigerator, storage

I stock food and follow this procedure, but can see that these are not only the same family - the gourd family, but also the same species.

Both have a hard outer shell.  Why does one ( Zucchini ) require refrigeration but not the others?

I would assume the answer holds true for cucumbers as well.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that they are different types of squash, although both are squash.

Zucchini is a summer squash, which has soft flesh and a malleable rind.

Both acorn and spaghetti squash, much like pumpkins, are winter squash, with harder flesh and a tough rind.  If cured, they can be stored for months at cool root cellar temperatures, and for a reasonable amount of time at regular room temperature.

Comment: what is the flesh and what is the rind? do you have a link?

Comment: The rind is the peel or outer skin; the flesh is the meaty part you eat.  I didn't look for references on this, although you can easily check the wikipedia article for each type of squash.

Comment: that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure they're not the same specie, as for your question, it's because zucchini is a summer squash and spaghetti and acorn squash are winter squashes, which has thinker rinds which insulates them

Comment: They actually are the same species https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_pepo

Comment: huh, the more I know, always thought summer squash were a different species to wintersquash

Comment: voted down because it was factually wrong