# How to store squash?

Tags: storage

I live in a small apartment with lots of windows.I do not have a basement.I read you can store squash a in cool, dark place for up to 3 months. Can I use a dark plastic bin to store it in or will it begin to rot without having a way to vent?

To start with I want to store spaghetti squash but I would also to look at storing acorn, butternut, zucchini. I live in an area where can buy lots of fresh vegetables and fruits and would like to buy more in bulk if possible.

Comment: There are **lots** of different kinds of squash and some of them (like pumpkins) store for months very easily... others, like zucchini and yellow squash, don't store for long at all. What specific type of squash are you interested in?

Comment: Related (types of squash): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40464/1672

Answer (score 2):

It is safe enough to store hardy squashes in an apartment, but more delicate ones such as zucchini and other thin-skinned squashes should probably be stored in the crisper of a refrigerator if you're planning to keep them for more than a week. If that space is not available, you can extend the "keep" time of less hardy squashes with just a bit of advance prep before storing. Seal the stem and blossom ends of the squash with melted candle wax, beeswax or paraffin. In a very clean sink, create a mixture of sterilizing water by making a strong brine, then adding one tablespoon (yes, tablespoon; it is, after all, a sterilizing agent) of bleach per gallon. Sink each squash in this rinse for a few seconds (I generally don't do it for more than 3 seconds, 5 if the peel is uneven or has scarring) and pat excess moisture off with a clean, non-abrasive, absorbent cloth. Allow the exterior of the squash to air dry before storing per the method for hardier squash.

For hardier squash, find the coolest location in your apartment that doesn't include a damp place like a bathroom or laundry. If it has a closet, you just found your storage place. Put down either a few small boards or a few bricks with several layers of cardboard. Perfect base. You can store your squashes right on there, or put them into cardboard boxes on top of that base, which is what I usually do. Don't let the squashes touch each other, as every point of contact is a potential weak spot. Turn your squash once a week; handle very gently to prevent even shallow, minor cosmetic bruising or abrasion of the skin, again in the interest of avoiding weak points. If you live in a relatively humid climate, melt candle wax or paraffin onto the squash where the stem meets the fruit -- after ensuring it is completely dry, of course -- to minimize the formation of molds and fungi.

Check hardy squashes for soft spots or mold each time you turn them, and immediately remove — and use — ones showing those signs. More delicate squashes should be checked every three days and should not be stored longer than two weeks, in case there is spoilage from the inside.

Comment: All squash? Including zucchini and yellow squash?

Comment: Sorry for the omission. This sounds stupid, but I don't really consider zucchini and such veggies to be real squashes, so I overlooked them. Mental block. By the way, the prep for the delicate stuff also works for cukes, melons, and (without the wax part) celery and grapes.

Comment: The common terms are "summer squash" and "winter squash".